# Azure PostgreSQL db is not saved correctly on file share

Tags: postgresql, azure, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to persist database data across web app restarts.
Here is the relevant docker compose config

```
  db:
    image:
    restart: always
    environment:
      ...
    ports:
      - 5332:5432
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql

volumes: 
   db-data:
      driver: azure_file
      driver_opts:
          share_name: ****
          storage_account_name: ****
          storageaccountkey: ****
```

The problem I'm facing is that in the file share the data isn't saved, there are the conf files but the data folder is empty.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I'm facing is that in the file share the data isn't saved

***Below is the Docker Compose file that sets up a PostgreSQL database service using an Azure file share for data persistence.***

**`docker-compose:`**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: your_username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: your_password
      POSTGRES_DB: your_database
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: your_share_name
      storage_account_name: your_storage_account_name
      storageaccountkey: your_storage_account_key
```

- Stop and restart the Docker containers using `docker-compose down` followed by `docker-compose up`.

```yaml
Creating network "teststorenetwrk01" with the default driver
Creating volume "testsampledata01" with azure_file driver
Pulling db (postgres:latest)...
latest: Pulling from library/postgres
6abc03819f3e: Pull complete
f9a1b35d1930: Pull complete
a141eade5523: Pull complete
87f146b69ff2: Pull complete
13f154e9e09e: Pull complete
7feeb07b9df5: Pull complete
d8d6bf88e0bb: Pull complete
e50f74169f44: Pull complete
21ff0a9a85d7: Pull complete
8b60b3148c4c: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:44f805f2d266a548a585e3aa6e37f04db90c6b69f3a82aa8399d6d9dabef86f4
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:latest
Creating testsampledata01 ... done
Attaching to testsampledata01
db_1  | 
db_1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1  | 
db_1  | 2024-03-05 10:27:05.366 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1  | 2024-03-05 10:27:05.366 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1  | 2024-03-05 10:27:05.366 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1  | 2024-03-05 10:27:05.368 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1  | 2024-03-05 10:27:05.371 UTC [1] LOG:  ending log output to stderr
db_1  | 2024-03-05 10:27:05.373 UTC [1] LOG:  initialized with md5 authentication
```

Here is my `file share` storage files.

[image]

- Here I have taken the sample data in postgres_db.

[image]

These are the file which persisted in my db.

[image]

After this configuration whenever my docker container running PostgreSQL also, the data is stored in the PostgreSQL database and remains intact and accessible.

Comment: Already tried this and gives error FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory

Comment: Try setting the correct ownership for the data directory in your Dockerfile. For example, if the user is postgres in the container - `RUN chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/data
`